# Web Crawler vs Html Parser

Tags: java, web-crawler, jsoup, crawler4j

What is the difference between web crawler and parser?

In java there are some name for fetching libraries . For example , they name nutch as a crawler and jsoup as a parser .

> Are they do the same purpose?

Are they fully similar for the job?

**thanks**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `jsoup` library is a Java library for working with real-world HTML. It is capable of **fetching** and working with HTML. However, it is **not** a Web-Crawler in general as it is only capable of fetching one page at a time (without writing a custom program (=crawler) using `jsoup` to fetch, extract and fetch new urls).

A Web crawler uses a HTML parser to **extract** URLs from a previously fetched Website and adds this newly discovered URL to its **frontier**.

A general sequence diagram of a Web crawler can be found in this answer: [What sequence of steps does crawler4j follow to fetch data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53351712/what-sequence-of-steps-does-crawler4j-follow-to-fetch-data/53670572#53670572)

**To summarize it:**

A HTML parser is a necessary component of a Web crawler for parsing and extracting URLs from given HTML input. However, a HTML parser alone, is **not** a Web crawler as it lacks some necessary features such as maintaining previously visted URLs, politeness, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is easily answered by looking this up on Wikipedia:

> A parser is a software component that takes input data (frequently
>   text) and builds a data structure

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages

> A Web crawler, sometimes called a spider or spiderbot and often
>   shortened to crawler, is an [Internet bot] that systematically browses
>   the World Wide Web, typically for the purpose of Web indexing (web
>   spidering).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler

Comment: But I didn't understand the major difference between them ?