# What sequence of steps does crawler4j follow to fetch data?

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

*I'd like to learn,*

1. how crawler4j works?
2. Does it fetch web page then   download its content and extract it ?
3. What about .db and .cvs file and its structures?

> Generally ,What sequences it follows?

please, I want a descriptive content

*Thanks*

Comment: Well, do you expect people explaining purpose and functionality of a software here on StackOverflow? Or would you think it makes more sense to read the documentation by yourself in order to solve your task/homework/assignment?

Comment: I didn't want examples or explanations I just want to know its sequences followed .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## General Crawler Process

The process for a typical multi-threaded crawler is as follows:

1. We have a queue data structure, which is called `frontier`. Newly discovered URLs (or start points, so-called seeds) are added to this datastructure. In addition, for every URL a unique ID is assigned in order to determine, if a given URL was previously visited.
2. Crawler threads then obtain URLs from the `frontier`  and schedule them for later processing.
3. The actual processing starts:

   - The `robots.txt` for the given URL is determined and parsed to honour exclusion criteria and be a polite web-crawler (configurable)
   - Next, the thread will check for politeness, i.e. time to wait before visting the same host of an URL again.
   - The actual URL is vistied by the crawler and the content is downloaded (this can be literally everything)
   - If we have HTML content, this content is parsed and potential new URLs are extracted and added to the frontier (in `crawler4j` this can be controlled via `shouldVisit(...)`).
4. The whole process is repeated until no new URLs are added to the `frontier`.

## General (Focused) Crawler Architecture

Besides the implementation details of `crawler4j` a more or less **general** (focused) crawler architecture (on a single server/pc) looks like this:

[image: basic crawler architecture]

Disclaimer: Image is my own work. Please respect this by referencing this post.